# How does Pci Passthrough work?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, gpu

If I configure my system GPU for PCI passthrough, will it stop working for the host machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your machine supports PCI passthrough, the host OS essentially becomes blind to the devices existing.  When I experimented it, you deliberately had the OS load a dummy driver to ensure that the host OS didn't try to use it.

Comment: That sure makes sense

Comment: It means the host device can no more use the device which is 'PCI passthrough' in my case my AMD GPU